# I am having trouble with installing library

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, shared-libraries

I am trying to use [jlatemath](https://github.com/noties/jlatexmath-android) library.
I have put the .jar file under libs folder,
and here is my gradle.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/jlatexmath-android-0.1.0-sources.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jlatexmath-android-font-cyrillic-0.1.0-sources.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jlatexmath-android-font-greek-0.1.0-sources.jar')
}
```

I don't think I need both, but I put them just to be sure.

I tried clean and rebuild the project.

The building is done without a problem without runtask,
but my code still not finding the classes from the library, which means the are not finding auto import for the classes.

It's the first time I am using a library so I might have missed something stupid, but it would be much appreciated if anyone could kindly let me know what it is.

Comment: Did you download files manually? or add as dependency?

Comment: paste your build.gradle (module:app) here.

Comment: @Nux yes I downloaded manually and added to libs folder. the code before was the gradle, I pasted the whole dependencies now.

Comment: I have answered your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Follow these steps]
What I have just noticed is that you are trying to download and add dependencies manually. That is very long and tiresome process! You can just paste and let android studio to do it for you.

For your case you need to add these lines in build.gradle

```
    implementation 'ru.noties:jlatexmath-android:0.1.0'

    // for Cyrillic symbols
    implementation 'ru.noties:jlatexmath-android-font-cyrillic:0.1.0'
```

And sync the project. Don't forget to delete all those lines which you used to add dependencies manually before.

so your code in the question supposed to look like this below

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


    //PASTE HERE DEPENDENCIES

    implementation 'ru.noties:jlatexmath-android:0.1.0'

    // for Cyrillic symbols
    implementation 'ru.noties:jlatexmath-android-font-cyrillic:0.1.0'
}
```

If it didnt fix your problem let me know.

If you prefer video tutorial, You can follow this tutorial for how to add dependency in android studio [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G27zMPLZm6o).

Comment: Oh, it worked!! I can't thank you enough! I added the lines starting with ru for the first time from instruction at the git, but it gave me an error that it can't find ru, so I deleted and manually added it. should've both I guess...? anyway thank you so much not only for this but also for my future as well!